# Is it unsafe to make the ID of table rows publicly available?

Tags: php, sql, database

So on my website, I have articles. Articles can be upvoted or downvoted.

In the URL of an article, you can quite clearly see its ID. For example:

> www.website.com/articles/**14**/this_is_the_article_title

And when you want to upvote/downvote the article, the post request uses the ID of the article as well without any kind of encoding.

Is this bad practice or unsafe? If so, what is the best alternative?

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/143253/is-it-vulnerable-to-let-users-know-their-own-and-other-users-id-from-a-database - a bit different but idea the same

Comment: Depends. Focus on core issue. Work back. Assume concern is serial/mass voting?

Comment: Yes in this instance it would be mass voting.

Comment: And being sequential integers it is easy to iterate on. So... You either make article identifiers hard to guess (hard to loop over, though nothing stopping me from scrapping them or whatever still) .- or you take the approach of validating the votes themselves on some sort of criteria. Time throttle, has user "read" said article, etc.

Comment: Used to work at a marketing company where people were compensated to watch videos. Had to verify they watched it by providing 3 short codes that were displayed during different parts of the video. Not saying you need to quiz them on reading comprehension but... I dunno, just felt like sharing that story really.

Comment: Sometimes it's good to take a heuristic approach. What is normal voting behavior? Once that is identified look for things outside the norms. Vote pattern / volume. If outside the threshold, flag it or whatever the course of action is.

Comment: I would say, yes. That's a security concern. Some web technologies secure it by default; JSF, for example.

Comment: But then you shouldn't provide anything like a table of contents or site map either. In fact, no links to the pages at all. One approach is integer IDs and then a unique random value (or some sort of hash on existing values from the article, and/or the user) - URI to article uses integer ID, link to vote pairs that ID and nonce.

Comment: A good alternative to sequence integer IDs are twitter snowflakes (google it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't say it is unsafe. A lot of sites use ID in URL. Either in GET or POST request but it is also used as a path variable.

If you consider web scraping your website unsafe than you can call it that because user can program a bot that goes in range from 0 to last user/post/product id and scrapes data. But you can avoid that if you use random id's. So for example you use different six digit id for every row in table. Instead of your id's going in ascending order you can generate random six digit code and give it to row if it isn't already in database.

So instead of rows going like this:

```
ID    NAME
0     [username]
1     [username]
2     [username]
```

You can build them like this:

```
ID      NAME
421456  [username]
197635  [username]
486597  [username]
```

Comment: True enough. I'd consider this basic obfuscation. Difficulty to spider/crawl the site vs iterate over IDs is pretty trivial. By virtue if your site is navigable -  and even somewhat SEO friendly shall we say? Then getting the article 6 digit codes is not a challenge/

Comment: Well yea, it is fairly easy process (depends on how many rows). But I would consider that to be the only "unsecure" thing about using id as path variable.

Comment: Not disagreeing. Speaks towards, "Focus on core issue. Work back."

Answer (score 0):

Feel like this is mostly about the discussion. Not sure this answer really helps / isn't totally obvious... But, assuming user needs to be authenticated to vote you could do something like this:

```
<?php
$articleId = 123; //these would be coming from $_GET.
$userId = 5001;
$somethingSalty = 'Constofsomesort' . floor(time() / 3600); //or no time aspect if you prefer

if ($articleId === $article->getId() 
         && $n === hash('sha256', $article->getId() . $user->getId() . $somethingSalty)) {...
```

And your vote URL's something like:

```
foo.com/vote?voteDir=1&articleId=123&n=cdc6365e49387cc04c6d2fa661670fb43c5473e0ae46480bf9512a30045b4829
```

- Vote link can't be shared.
- Are unique per article/user and shouldn't be spoof-able.
- Mitigates "replay attacks".